# Is there anything like standard IP camera OS emulator?

Tags: webcam, emulation, operating-system, ip-camera

Is there anything like standard IP camera OS emulator? So to create a plugin\program for it and be able to come to Cameras creator\vendor with something like "Hey, I've developed some cool software for your camera! Look here! Please implement it into your cameras next version or please give me the job in your company!)"

So something like mobile os emulator... But for IP or at least usb Web Cameras.. So to create and test modules for it.

So Point is not in IP cameras HTTP\RTSP apis emulation but in emulation of how camera works internaly (like how frames are obtained, compressed, what controlls all that process etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this is what you are looking for exactly. http://sourceforge.net/projects/axisemulator/

Comment: Nope.. It just emulates a resulting work of IP camera (like HTTP requests API and outgoing MJPEG streams) but it does not provide emulation for how camera works internaly (like how frames are obtained, compressed, what controlls all that process etc)